# How to make serialize the contents of, and make sense of, log files?

Tags: serialization, hadoop

I'm looking for insight into what tools are available to help with my situation. I have several servers that are all running various programs (these programs are doing 24/7 background processing tasks). All of these programs generate log files, stored on their local machines. Each log file has its own unique structure, but in general they're all just plain text log files.

I'm looking for some tool that I can use to serialize the data inside all of these log files and then be able to query on the data.

Is this something that Hadoop Hive is built to do? It sounds like it, but I am looking for insight into this particular scenario of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is, it depends. Lets say the data you are trying to serialize is scattered in the log lines but there is a way to group the scattered information using a key then you can write a `Mapper` which gets each line as input to get the key and have the `Reducer` group the log lines by key. The reducer can also build a custom object which implements `Writable` and write the object to a `SequenceFile`. This is just one scenario. Before you stat go over the [link](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/mapreduce-patterns/) as it has the most common and advanced usage/patters of MapReduce.

Good Luck!!